# Trig Mountain Problem

Tags: trigonometry

I have a math problem. 
Someone is on a football field and they are looking at a mountain. The angle of elevation from the floor to the mountain is 16 degrees. That person walks 127 meters towards the mountain and now it's 23 degrees. 
 How high is the mountain? 
I got 177m.

The way I solved it was by finding the difference in the angles and the difference in the distance away from the mountain. 
X:16
X+127:23

Using that I was able to get 
127:7

And with that ended up with 
18.1428571429 
I then multiplied that by 23 to get the bottom length of the triangle. 
417.285714286

Which I put into tan 
tan23 = y/417.285714286
417.285714286*tan23 = y 
y = 177.127276878 
It is never stated how far away they are at the start either

Comment: Could you show your working please? That will ensure that you get the best responses possible. Is there anything in particular you're unclear about?

Comment: Yeah I changed it so I explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h = AB$ be the height of the mountain.

Let the person be initially at $C$, then moved $127$ m  to $D$ such that $BD = x$. So $BC = x+127$ m .

[image]

From the triangle $ABD$
$\cot(23^\circ) = \frac{x}{h} \Rightarrow \boxed{x = h\cot(23^\circ)}$

Similarly from triangle $ABC$

$x+127 = h\cot(16^\circ) \Rightarrow h\cot(23^\circ)  +127 = h\cot(16^\circ) \Rightarrow \boxed{h  = \frac{127}{\cot(16^\circ) - \cot(23^\circ)} \approx 112.234 \text{ m}} $

---

As mentioned in the comments below, $\cot$ is reciprocal of $\tan$. If you still have doubts, then in terms of $\tan$,

$\tan(23^\circ) = \frac h x \Rightarrow x = \frac{h}{\tan 23^\circ}$

and $x + 127 = \frac{h}{\tan 16 ^ \circ} \Rightarrow h = \frac{127}{\frac1{\tan 16^\circ} - \frac1{\tan23^\circ}} \approx 112.234 \text{ m}$

Comment: Can you explain how this works?

Comment: What is cot? I havent seen it before. Is it just cos?

Comment: Nope, $\cot$ or cotangent is the reciprocal of the tangent or $\tan$ function.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: I've added some points, is it clear now?

Comment: Yeah thank you so much!